# I'm not able to send messages using the mail() PHP function

Tags: php, html, contact-form, sendmessage

I'm not able to find the error in my code. My PHP code is in my index.html file. I'm not able to send messages from my static webpage.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <form action="index.html" method="POST" class="contact-form" role="form">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Your Full Name">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your E-mail">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subj" name="subj" placeholder="Your Subject">
        <textarea id="mssg" name="mssg" placeholder="Your Message" class="form-control" rows="10"></textarea>
        <input class="btn btn-main btn-lg" type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" data-loading-text="<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Sending...">
    </form>
</div>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $to = 'email@company.com';
    $siteName = 'http://www.website.com';
    $name = $_POST['fname'];
    $mail = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = $_POST['subj'];
    $message = $_POST['mssg'];
    $mailSub = '[Contact] [' . $siteName . '] '.$subject;

    $body = 'Sender Name: ' . $name . "\n\n";
    $body .= 'Sender Mail: ' . $mail . "\n\n";
    $body .= 'Message Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n";
    $body .= 'Message: ' . $message;

    $header = 'From: ' . $mail . "\r\n";
    $header .= 'To:  ' . $to . "\r\n";

    mail($to, $mailSub, $body, $header);
}else{
    echo '0';
}
?>
```

I receive an error every time i try to send a message through my website. Thank you!

Comment: " I receive an error every time i try to send a message through my website" what error?

Comment: `action="index.html"` did you instruct your system to handle `.html` files as PHP? If not, then *"Houston, we have a problem"*.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at `action="index.html"` could be a problem if you did not instruct your system to treat `.html` files as PHP.

If not, then you will need to change it to a `.php` file extension and renaming your present file to accomodate it. Then change your action value to direct to that file.

For example:

`<form action="script.php" method="post">`

- `script.php` being your present PHP handler.